# How to creating new var and get value by user in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I'm working on my first app using React-Native and I want to make some variables using Text Field with simple math. For example, I want to do the following:

(This is not coding this what I want to do in my app).

```
get a,b,c from user 
Result1= a+b ;
Result2 = Result1 - c ;
```

How I can do it?

Comment: My dear friend. Why don't you start form here??  https://codingiseasy.com/react-native-calculator-app-part-1/ or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TkYTPSVvMaM

Comment: Furthermore your question I so huge ....

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a great tutorial site, and your question is too broad. Luckily, the answer to your query is easily found with a simple web search for "react native calculator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I told this website is not a tutorial website. However I think you posted this question for more than 5 times! 
So,To get the info form user you have to use the input text you can use the states inside your component. Try to put this code in App.js or call this component there:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, TextInput, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class PizzaTranslator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }

  cal=()=>{   
    var result= +this.state.a + +this.state.b ;
    var varFinalResult=result-this.state.c;
    this.setState({varFinalResult})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{padding: 10}}>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Type here a!"
          onChangeText={(a) => this.setState({a})}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Type here b!"
          onChangeText={(b) => this.setState({b})}
        />
    <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Type here c!"
          onChangeText={(c) => this.setState({c})}
        />
     <Text>{this.state.varFinalResult}</Text>
     <Button
       onPress={this.cal}
       title="calculation"
       color="#841584"
       accessibilityLabel="calculation"
      />

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Don't give up in programming and start with that links.

Comment: thanks a lot it's working but there was a little mistake in your code but I fix it  : 
    var result= +this.state.a+ +this.state.b;

Comment: @J.Doe your welcome. If it was helpful for, please accept it as a correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you have a text field you should use state to set and get the text
refere to this link.

> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text

react native uses javascript so you should have a background about it first (like how to define varibles....)
the equivalent code to what you asked for in javascript is

```
let { a, b, c  } = user;
let Result1 = a + b;
let Result2 = Result1 - c;
```